# Extjs 7 Community Edition. Cannot install ext-gen

Tags: javascript, npm, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

I am able to log into the sencha NPM repo using:

```
npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/ --scope=@sencha
```

It says:

```
Logged in as stevemc to scope @sencha on https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/.
```

But when I go to install ext-gen with the command:

```
npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen
```

I am told:

```
403 You are not allowed to access this feed. - GET https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/@sencha%2fext-gen
```

I've tried the recommended trouble shooting actions of deleting the `.npmrc` file and cleaning the NPM cache. But to no avail. I left it for a day to see if things changed the next day (maybe it was just some sort of update delay). But no.

I'm lost for ideas now.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem. turns out the url for the registry is wrong (the documentation is wrong too). just change the registry to https://sencha.myget.org/F/gpl/npm/, so the command is: npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/gpl/npm/ --scope=@sencha
and you are good to go

Comment: I am curious, where did you find that information?

Comment: wow its work in 2023, sencha need to change their documentation